# How can I get the point from psd file

Tags: java, point, psd

I have read the  but I still did not understand this paragraph:

> All points used in defining a path are stored in eight bytes as a pair
>   of 32-bit components, vertical component first. The two components are
>   signed, fixed point numbers with 8 bits before the binary point and 24
>   bits after the binary point. Three guard bits are reserved in the
>   points to eliminate most concerns over arithmetic overflow. Hence, the
>   range for each component is 0xF0000000 to 0x0FFFFFFF representing a
>   range of -16 to 16. The lower bound is included, but not the upper
>   bound. This limited range is used because the points are expressed
>   relative to the image size. The vertical component is given with
>   respect to the image height, and the horizontal component is given
>   with respect to the image width. [ 0,0 ] represents the top-left
>   corner of the image; [ 1,1 ] ([ 0x01000000,0x01000000 ]) represents
>   the bottom-right. In Windows, the byte order of the path point
>   components are reversed; you should swap the bytes when accessing each
>   32-bit value.

I have done a test of that: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGE1O.png)

and get the point of that:

- x1:7e0e42    y1:0
- x2:7e0e42    y2:0
- x3:7e0e42    y3:0
- x1:1000000   y1:0
- x2:1000000   y2:0
- x3:1000000   y3:0
- the fisrt is at the top left of red rect;
- the second is at the top
- right of red rect;
- the canvas width is 790px
- the top left is at 389px

How can I get the number of 389 from 7e0e42?
I just can not understand the meaning of that paragraph.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but:

Your first `x` value is `0x007e0e42` in the fixed point representation mentioned in the text. That means `0 + 0x7e0e42 / 0xffffff`, or  0.49240505695343 (approximately) in floating point.

Remember, the coordinates are given *"relative to the image size"*. If you multiply this with the the image width of 790, you get 388.999994993209839, which should round nicely to 389, which is what you expected.

Mystery solved. :-)